# Can someone give an example of an op-amp whose positive and negative slew rates are different?

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, slew-rate

Can someone give an example of an operational amplifier whose positive and negative slew rates are different from each other? I have searched for it in the book *Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits*, but I could not find one.

Comment: I've never seen one from what I remember. Maybe you should explain why you think one is of interest to you?

Comment: Confirmed. Statistically "equal".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [LT1056](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/design-notes/dn043f.pdf). Asymmetry can be ~2:1 for this type of op-amp.

[image]

> A case in point is that of the available P-channel JFET input op amps,
> many which have a characteristic SR response which is asymmetrical. In
> fact, popular op amps with topologies like the original 355/356 types
> are intrinsically faster for negative going output swings than they
> are for positive. Similar comments apply to such related devices as
> the OP15, OP16, etc. Since this type of JFET device topology was
> introduced, the SR specifi ed on the data sheet has typically been the
> lower of two dissimilar rates, i.e., the slower, positive edge SR.
> Thus, given an op amp with a typical SR spec of 14V/μs for positive
> going edges, the same amp will have a corresponding negative SR of
> about 28V/μs

Comment: And what are the "benefits" of such dissymmetry?

Comment: @Antonio51 There might be some in a nonlinear circuit, but I think it's just a characteristic of that  type of part that you have to live with.

Comment: Ok. I guess it is only in fast "circuits" that this can happens ...